# Column calculations with Autocolumns

Tags: tabulator

I'm currently using tabulator 4.7.

I have a dynamic table and am using the autocolumns option to load the data.
How can I get the calculations(Sum) for the supporting columns with autocolumns.

Current code used:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
              data: data,
              autoColumns: true,
              selectable: true,
              }
            });
```

Comment: @Oli Folkerd can this be achieved with autoColumnsDefinitions?